# How to pan and zoom .svg on android?

Tags: android, svg, webview, zooming, pan

I'm using webview to view a .svg file (located in assets folder). In the preview mode of the.svg on android studio, I can pan and zoom perfectly. But when I export to .apk, pan and zoom is not working at all on the app.

Note: The .svg file I'm using for test is this: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ghostscript_Tiger.svg

Can you help me solve this please?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    //webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");


    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Locater(), "locater");
    //webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/gallardo.svg");
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Tiger.svg");
}}
```

Comment: The SVG preview inside Android Studio is just that - a preview of what the SVG looks like.  Have you tried testing it in the Android emulator?  Or is that what you mean (it works in the emulator, but not on a real device)?

Comment: Also what is the "Locater" class?

Comment: Yeah. It's working inside Android Studio (as preview). And as I'm not using Android Studio emulator. I build an APK, and test it (outsite Android Studio) on an external emulator (MEMU) and "here" pan and zoom don't work.
About the locater class, I don't what it is. I just watched and follow a kind of tutorial for webview. But if it's something bad with it I can change it.

Comment: did you solve this issue?